# вносить данные из словаря в файл, который уже содержит данные

Tags: словари

Допустим есть файл в котором содержится `q1=a1\nq2=a2`. В самом коде

```css
_dict = dict(pair.replace('\n', '').split('=') for pair in open('file','r'))
_dict['q3'] = 'a3'
```

На самом деле ключей больше и названия более сложные. Мне нужно считывать данные из файла в словарь, вносить данные в словарь, и внесенные данные в словарь в ходе выполнения программы вписать в файл.  Вопрос такой, какой наилучший способ реализовать внесения данных (что были внесены в словарь в ходе выполнения программы) в файл из словаря. Желательно не перезаписывая файл полностью

Answer (score 1):

**Вместо** *smth* абсолютный\полный путь к файлу

```py
with open('smth','r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    new_data, _dict = data.split('\n'), {}
    for element in new_data:
        _list = element.split('=')
        _dict[_list[0]] = _list[1]
```

Смотря в каком виде надо дозаписывать данные в словарь, но считать можно так